# Need to reset a counter variable in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop

Ok so I need to make an array using a for loop that is the following

```
      [13 14 15]
      [10 11 12]
      [7 8 9]
      [4 5 6]
      [1 2 3]
```

here's what I have so far. It works but the function could be alot prettier

```
clc
clear all
m=1;
i=0;
for m=1:15
    i=i+1;
    if m<=3
    matrix(5,i)=m;
    end
    if m>3 && m<=6
    matrix(4,i-3)=m;
        end
        if m>6 && m<=9
    matrix(3,i-6)=m;
        end
        if m>9 && m<=12
    matrix(2,i-9)=m;
        end
        if m>12 && m<=15
    matrix(1,i-12)=m;
        end
    end
```

I want to get rid of the i-12 etc. by maybe using another for loop that infinitely counts from 1 to three and terminates through a different parameter?

Been fiddling with this one for a while.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (and should!) skip the loops entirely:

```
flipud(reshape(1:15, 3, 5)')
```

A loop based solution probably wants to use *nested* loops to keep that `i` variable of yours resetting. After that we have a couple of options. But if you are using loops, always remember to pre-allocate memory for `matrix`:

indexing into a pre-computed vector of numbers:

```
k = 1:15;
n = 1;
matrix = zeros(5,3);
for m = 5:-1:1
    for i = 1:3
        matrix(m,i) = k(n);
        n = n+1;
    end
end
```

Or else using some arithmetic tricks:

```
matrix = zeros(5,3);
for m = 1:5
    for i = 1:3
        matrix(m,i) = (5-m)*3 +i;
    end
end
```

Comment: Woah. That's cool! But I think that's a bit out of my league... I've been asked to use loops in this problem

Comment: This is more what I was looking for. Doesn't quite make the array but I think I can work with this.. Thanks!